# Textures not aligning with edges

Tags: uv-image-editor

does anyone know how to fix this issue with materials not lining up with the other edge? Ive attached a photo of my problem and I'm sure it's an easy fix but I don't have crazy experience with blender and having trouble with this. It is scaled/uv smart projected only but even with moving the material around in UV editing, it never matches up. [image]

Comment: Unwrap again, with some seams where you want to cut the UVs, but not where you want the image to be continued. But even if you cut, you can align the UVs in the UV Editor

Comment: can you attach your blend file so we can help fix it https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: I tried to upload to blend exchange but I keep getting the error "all uploaded files must be in the blend file format" when the file is a .blend?

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lfZUCQbzw3HrzcaaFcT3oiSnWedF7qRr/view?usp=sharing let me know if that works

Comment: Texture is missing, you can pack it into the blend file with menu *File > External Data > Pack Resources* then upload blend file again on https://blend-exchange.com and btw your face normals are pointing outwards, they need to point inwards since your model is on the inside.  Select all faces in *Edit Mode* and go to menu *Mesh > Normals > Recalculate Inside*

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie ive attached the link to the updated file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k_cPbfh9Lon0hr65rlUBpQCoo1onAInG/view?usp=sharing